# Items and Subitems in List-View control

Tags: c, winapi

I'm want to use a `List-View` control to display results of an LDAP search in a "grid". I've written some test code to see how it works, but it's not being displayed as I want. As I understand it, each `Item` is equivalent to a "row" (using `LVS_REPORT`style), and the `Subitem` is equivalent to a "column" (e.g. for each item I can display a number of subitems, each in a separate column on the same row).

Here's my test code, currently set to create four columns, with a single Item and four Subitems (corresponding to the four columns). Two functions: one to create the columns, the other to insert items.

```
int CreateColumns(HWND *hwndlistbox)
{
    wchar_t *cnames[100];
    LVCOLUMN lvc;
    int i;

    cnames[0] = L"column1";
    cnames[1] = L"column2";
    cnames[2] = L"column3";
    cnames[3] = L"column4";
    cnames[4] = NULL;

    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;

    for (i = 0; cnames[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        lvc.iSubItem = i;
        lvc.pszText = cnames[i];
        lvc.cx = 100;
        lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;

        ListView_InsertColumn(*hwndlistbox, i, &lvc);
    }

    return i;
}

void InsertItems(HWND *hwndlistbox, int *columncount)
{
    LVITEM lvi;
    wchar_t *items[100];
    int i, j;

    items[0] = L"text1";
    items[1] = L"text2";
    items[2] = L"text3";
    items[3] = L"text4";
    items[4] = NULL;

    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvi.iItem = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < *columncount; i++)
    {
        lvi.pszText = items[i];
        lvi.iSubItem = i;
        ListView_InsertItem(*hwndlistbox, &lvi);
    }
}
```

I expect this to generate a single row (`lvi.iItem = 0;`) with a text string under each column (`lvi.iSubItem = i;`). This is what it displays instead:

[image]

Changing `lvi.iSubItem = i` to `lvi.iSubItem = 0` results in each text string being displayed as a new row in the first column:

[image]

I've played around with it, hardcoding the numbers on both `iItem` and `iSubItem`, changing both to `i`, but I can't get it to display the text anywhere other than the first column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your `cnames` and `items` arrays are declared as array of pointers, but you are not allocating memory for them; you would need to declare them as an array of strings, like `wchar_t cnames[100][40];`.

Secondly, you need to use `ListView_InsertItem` to insert an item and set the value for the first column, then use [ListView_SetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775091(v=vs.85).aspx) to add additional columns, like

```
lvi.pszText = items[0];
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
ListView_InsertItem(*hwndlistbox, &lvi);
for (i = 1; i < *columncount; i++)
{   lvi.pszText = items[i];
    lvi.iSubItem = i;
    ListView_SetItem(*hwndlistbox, &lvi);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. Re: memory, this was just some test code with hardcoded strings; the "real" internals will be different.

Answer (score 3):

Each row shows a single item so you cannot populate the columns by adding items.

As [the documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

"You cannot use `ListView_InsertItem` or `LVM_INSERTITEM` to insert subitems. The `iSubItem` member of the `LVITEM` structure must be zero. See `LVM_SETITEM` for information on setting subitems."

The [LVM_SETITEM documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains how to set the text of a sub-item.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I accepted the other answer due to the example which I was able to use.