# What is the purpose of LVCOLUMN.iSubItem?

Tags: listview, winapi

I don't understand what is the purpose of `LVCOLUMN.iSubItem`. This is what MSDN says:

> iSubItem
>
> ```
> Type: int
>
> Index of subitem associated with the column.
> ```

I first thought that it means that when I create a column, I can set an index to the column, for example: 123, and then when I want to insert some data into the column, I just supply the number 123 as an identification to the column.

But it does not work, no matter what indexes I set to the columns, the columns are still numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: I have two guesses. Either 1) you did not specify `LVCF_SUBITEM` in `LVCOLUMN.mask`, or 2) the `iSubItem` is only used by `LVM_GETCOLUMN` (for instance, for getting the subitem of a column based on its order after rearranging). Nothing in the documentation points to the latter explanation, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `LVCOLUMN.iSubItem` is numbered sequentially from 0, left to right as you found out.  Yes, it certainly looks like it has no purpose since you must always specify the column number to do anything with an LVCOLUMN.  So it just gives you back what you already know.

Hard to guess how this happened, other than to note that the common controls were not exactly Microsoft's finest moment.  I suspect it *might* have something to do with the `LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP` on a listview.  That allows the user to re-arrange the columns by dragging them.  Now the column index you pass to LVM_GETCOLUMN gets a bit murky, is it supposed to indicate the *position* or the *original* index of the column?  They went with the latter and used `LVM_GETCOLUMNORDERARRAY` if you need to know how the user arranged the columns.

Or they simply mirrored `LVITEM.iSubItem` to keep the structures similar, somewhat likelier perhaps.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: The iSubItem member is the ListCtrl iSubItem.  When in report mode, the user could drag columns in a different order, hide a column, or insert a new one, if you application allows.  The iSubItem will always stay the same for a given column, tying it to the information you supply and stays the same for the life of the control.

Answer (score 1):

The subitem is only valid and functional for list controls with the style LVS_REPORT. You need to insert columns to use it.

With this style you add items LVM_INSERTITEM, and each item can have subitems. To address the contents of a subitem you need the member of the structure.

Comment: "To address the contents of a subitem you need the member of the structure" This is why I asked this question, the member of the structure (`LVCOLUMN.iSubItem`) is irrelevant, and the columns are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the LVS_REPORT style, the list view control looks like a grid control.

In this case, items are stored in column 0 and sub items represent what's stored 
in other columns (there is not a whole concept such as a "cell"). So, the subitem index is notably used with the [LVM_SETITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb761186.aspx) and [LVM_GETITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb774953.aspx) messages (or with corresponding [ListView_SetItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb775091.aspx) and [ListView_GetItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb761308.aspx) macros), to write or read column X text value for example. Depending on index you access the item, if iSubItem == 0, or a subitem, if iSubItem >= 1.

You can have a look at this question here on SO for extra sample: [Items and Subitems in List-View control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323468/items-and-subitems-in-list-view-control)